# How broken is this android studio installation when it fails at this point of installing haxm?

Tags: android-studio

I set android studio to be installed on an external drive (though that probably won't make a difference)

I ran the android studio installation for a while.

Then while i'm watching a video on youtube, then, from nowhere, a window popped up, the kind of window that asks for administrative privileges for the cmd prompt! Of course I said no. I don't/didn't know what program is requesting it.

After I said no, I checked how the android installation was going and I saw this

[image]

so the installation fails at

```
Running Intel® HAXM installer
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
```

There's no option to attempt that part again..

Now sure I can see that it's probably possible to install it from within android studio. But i'm familiar with the kind of poorly written installation programs that software frequently use or just generally how typically written software deals with errors, just showing the first it runs into and no others, and in the case of an installation, e.g. it's often the case that there's other stuff that it would do after the thing that failed (HAXM in this case), so if I just tried to go into android studio and then install HAXM then there may be other things missing from my installation.

The installation has run for a while, but there's no back button.

I'm not sure what route to take to get android studio fully installed at this stage. At the moment the only safe option seems to me to be reinstalling android studio (and of course clicking yes next time the UAC window pops up!).

Comment: What exactly is the problem with just running the installer again to be on the safe side?

Comment: @MattGibson the issue with doing that is it takes quite a long time so i'm hoping there's a quicker way that is safe.